# Maching two words as a single word

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-analyzers

Consider that I have a document which has a field with the following content: `5W30 QUARTZ INEO MC 3 5L`

A user wants to be able to search for `MC3` (no space) and get the document; however, search for `MC 3` (with spaces) should also work. Moreover, there can be documents that have the content without spaces and that should be found when querying with a space.

I tried indexing without spaces (e.g. `5W30QUARTZINEOMC35L`), but that does not really work as using a wildcard search I would match too much, e.g. MC35 would also match, and I only want to match two exact words concatenated together (as well as exact single word).

So far I'm thinking of additionally indexing all combinations of two words, e.g. `5W30QUARTZ`, `QUARTZINEO`, `INEOMC`, `MC3`, `35L`. However, does Elasticsearch have a native solution for this?

Comment: Are you able to resolve issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you want can be done with the [shingle token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html). Depending on your mapping, I would imagine you'd need to add a filter looking something like this to your content field to get your tokens indexed in pairs:

```
"filter_shingle":{
   "type":"shingle",
   "max_shingle_size":2,
   "min_shingle_size":2,
   "output_unigrams":"true"
}
```

Note that this is also already the default configuration, I just added it for clarity.